# Number of odd and even natural solutions

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to prove or disprove the following statement:

> Number of even natural solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x _4=14$ is equal to the number of odd natural solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x _4=14$.

I think that they should be equal because of symmetry but it does not feel true. How to approach this issue?

Comment: Did you already try to compute the actual numbers separately?

Comment: With "even natural solutions" do you mean that each x_i is even?

Comment: @user627482 I guess. I just copied from the my book.

Answer (score 7):

By letting $x_1'=x_1+1$, $x_2'=x_2+1$, $x_3'=x_1-1$ and $x_4'=x_4-1$, we can produce an odd solution $(x_1',x_2',x_3',x_4')$ from an even solution $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$. Since this mapping is injective, we know that there are more or equal number of odd solutions than that of even solutions. But this mapping is not surjective since e.g. $(3,1,5,5)$ is not in the image. Thus we conclude there are more odd solutions than even solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 'natural' means 'positive integer':

The total number of solutions is:$$\binom{14-1}{4-1}=286$$

Even solutions are positive integer solutions to $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=7$, where $y_i=\frac{x_i}{2}$
The number of even solutions is:$$\binom{7-1}{4-1}=20$$

Odd solutions are positive integer solutions to $z_1+z_2+z_3+z_4=9$, where $z_i=\frac{x_i+1}{2}$
The number of odd solutions is:$$\binom{9-1}{4-1}=56$$

Comment: For the odd part, why is it $9$ and not $7$?

Comment: Because it is $(14+4)/2$

Comment: Why do you add $4$?

Comment: @kickstart Starting with $x_1+x_2+x_3+x _4=14$ with all $x_i$ odd, we add $1$ to each $x_i$ to get $(x_1+1)+(x_2+1)+(x_3+1)+(x _4+1)=14+4$. Divide by $2$ and let $z_i=\frac{x_i}{2}$ to get $z_1+z_2+z_3+z_4=9$